# JavaFX Table shows an Element, but doesnt display text

Tags: java, javafx

I am pretty unexperienced with JavaFX:

I load the View of my "game" and want to fill a table with Rooms a Player can goto from his current room. I get the data from the model, add it to an list, add the list to the table view. This worked fine previously, but now I am experiencing a problem:

When I run the code, the Table does show an Element, but not the name of it. I can select it (and I guess work with it, I havent implemented more) but the name String is missing. I tried to do the `setVisability()` trick to update the Table (this was usefull before to force a refresh when data has changed) but it didnt help either.

```
public class GameViewController implements Printable{

private MainApp mainApp;
private ObservableList<Room> exitList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private TableView<Room> exitTable; 
@FXML
private TableColumn<Room, String>exitNameColumn;


public GameViewController(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp=mainApp;
}

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    update();
}

public void update() {
    for (Room room: mainApp.getGame().getPlayer().getCurrentRoom().getExitList()) {
        exitList.add(room);
    }
    exitTable.setItems(exitList);
    exitNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
    exitTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
    exitTable.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]

PS: And the returning method for the property is:

```
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}
```

PPS: Room class (with nameProperty as field)

```
public class Room 
{

private String name;
private StringProperty nameProperty;
private boolean visible = false;
private HashMap<String, Room> exits;        

public Room(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
    nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
}

//other methods

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return nameProperty;
}

public ArrayList<Room> getExitList() {
    ArrayList<Room> list = new ArrayList<Room>(exits.values());
    return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `nameProperty()` method probably shouldn't be creating a new property every time it is invoked. Can you post the complete `Room` class (at least everything associated with `name`)?

Comment: You should store your nameProperty as a field.

Comment: @user629735 I added the room class. I tried using a field but it looks like it doesnt chage anything.

Comment: @James_D also added a screen

Comment: Everything you've posted indicates it should work. I assume you have done some debugging or logging to check that the `Room` instances in the `exitList` actually have a value for `name`. See if you can create a [MCVE] that replicates the issue.

Comment: Whups. I just checked the first value in the column and it gives back "null". So i assume there is a problem filling up the table with`exitNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());`

Comment: Well, its actually looks like the stringproperty object is null. I tried doing something like this: `this.nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
        nameProperty.set(name);` but its still null when I check it later.

Comment: `exitNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(...)` does not "fill up the table": it merely tells the column how to get the data from the `Room` instance representing the row. If you call `nameProperty.set(name);` and then `nameProperty().get()` returns `null`, the only possibility is that `name` must have been `null` in the first place.

Comment: Also note that once you have the `StringProperty nameProperty` field there is no point in also having a `String name` field. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) for correct implementation of the JavaFX property pattern.

Comment: just fixed the problem, I had falsly set 2 TableColumns from different TableViews with the same fx:id and that appeared to cause the trouble. Was a bad misstake I didnt find even during double checking. Anyway, thank your for taking your time!